# Mongoose populate() issue: Error in Debug, and null in data output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

All - I know there are already quite a few posts around Mongoose populate() not working. I browsed them all, read the doc many times... yet I'm unsuccessful in trying to reference documents in other collections. Here it just returns/sets `null` (data captured from api):

```
"data": [
    {
      "checkin_date": "2018-01-19T07:50:31.220Z",
      "created_at": "2018-01-20T21:27:34.925Z",
      "updated_at": "2018-01-20T21:27:34.925Z",
      "_id": "5a61a3479e082a15e3d9add5",
      "checkin_comment": "Loving it!",
      "rating_score": 4,
      "user": null, // <--------------- issue is here
      "id": "5a61a3479e082a15e3d9add5"
    }
]
```

I've enabled debug in Mongoose, and here's the output when querying /checkins

```
Running on localhost:3000
Connected.....
Mongoose: checkins.find({}, { sort: { checkin_date: -1 }, fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd"), ObjectId("5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd") ] } }, { fields: {} })
The user is undefined
```

Manually querying through the MongoDB console, correctly returns the user document. Successful query below:

```
> db.users.find({ _id: ObjectId("5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd") })
```

Some code now.

```
const express     = require('express');
const router      = express.Router();
const ObjectID    = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const Checkin     = require('../models/checkin');

router.get('/checkins', (req, res, err) => {
  Checkin.find()
    .sort( { checkin_date: -1 } )
    .populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        return res.send(err);
      console.log('The user is %s', result.user);
      res.json({ status: 200, data: result, message: null });
    });
});
```

The models now. The Checkin one first:

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

var checkinSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  checkin_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true
  },
  checkin_comment: {
    type: String,
    max: 140
  },
  rating_score: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0.5,
    max: 5
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Checkin', checkinSchema);
```

The User model:

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  is_private: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true
  },
  user_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 8
  },
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 100
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 100
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date_joined: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  checkins: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Checkin'
  }],
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

userSchema.virtual('displayName').get(function () {
  return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
});

userSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
  return '/user/' + this.user_name;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Thanks to everyone who read it all... and apologies for the lengthy post, but wanted to provide as much insight as possible.

Thanks. -X.

Comment: Is the user's objectid (*5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd*) actually stored in the user field of the checkin document?

Comment: @MikaS - It is: `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a61a3479e082a15e3d9add5"),
 "checkin_date" : 1516348231220,
 "checkin_comment" : "Loving it!",
 "rating_score" : 4,
 "user" : {
  "_id" : "5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd"
 }
}`

Comment: Ah, your comment @MikaS made me look at it... I actually thought that I had to put the _id field in there... while I just needed to get the `user:` field the ObjectId value... *sigh*